# GBM package: Why there is a missing node?

Tags: missing-data, boosting

Why there is a missingNode as 3 as there are no missing values?

I have the data in the following form:

```
Y Score ot
1    10 3
0     7 2
0     9 2
0    22 1
0     5 2
```

Then

```
rawData <- read.delim("file.txt", header=TRUE, sep=" ");
data <- rawData[,c("Score","ot")];
y <- data[,c("Y")];
train.data <- as.data.frame(data);
train.data$y <- y;

fit.adaboost <- gbm(y ~ ., data=train.data, dist="adaboost", n.tree = 200,
    shrinkage = 1, train.fraction = (2/12));
pretty.gbm.tree(fit.adaboost,i.tree =2);
```

When I do pretty I see

```
    SplitVar SplitCodePred LeftNode RightNode MissingNode ErrorReduction Weight Prediction
  0        0     6.5000000        1         2           3       3007.974  49087 -0.2998575
  1       -1     0.8330843       -1        -1          -1          0.000   3061  0.8330843
  2       -1    -0.3752048       -1        -1          -1          0.000  46026 -0.3752048
  3       -1    -0.2998575       -1        -1          -1          0.000  49087 -0.2998575
```

Comment: Welcome to CV. I edited your post so it is readable. For computer output and such, put 4 spaces before each line and it will then format it one line at a time. Also, please look at your posting yourself and make sure people can read and understand it.

Answer (score 1):

`gbm` always selects a surrogate for each split. This is useful for prediction in new data when some observations may be missing on those predictors even if the training sample was fully observed.